# Expo bundler failing to find file

Tags: react-native, expo

I getting an error from time to time on React Native with Expo (managed pipeline), where it states something like:

```
While trying to resolve module `expo-random` from file `E:\source\app\node_modules\expo-auth-session\build\PKCE.js`, the package `E:\source\app\node_modules\expo-random\package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself 
specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`E:\source\app\node_modules\expo-random\build\Random.js`. 
Indeed, none of these files exist:

  * E:\source\app\node_modules\expo-random\build\Random.js(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
  * E:\source\app\node_modules\expo-random\build\Random.js\index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
```

However, expo is mistaken, the required file does exist:

```
❯ ls .\node_modules\expo-random\build\Random.js  


    Directory: E:\source\app\node_modules\expo-random\build


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        26/10/1985     05:15           2331 Random.js
```

This time expo is complaining about expo-random, but I'm getting this error on different packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was intermittent, so I ended up finding out what *I* was doing wrong: I would install packages while expo was running and this *sometimes* would cause the error above.

Silly mistake; but I'm leaving it here in case someone has the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install expo-random from [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/random/)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similaire error today trying to install expo-auth-session
so I just installed expo-random and it worked

```
npm i expo-random
```